# How do I get dotCover to filter out files with a <auto-generated> comment

Tags: entity-framework, dotcover

Is there a way to make dotCove ignore all files that have the  comment at the top, e.g. for Entity Framework generated classes?

I'm aware of the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute and use it for other scenarios.

Comment: The tag was removed, this is what it looks like:

Comment: `//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: Although this functionality isn't supported you could put your EF classes in a separate assembly and then exclude that assembly from the coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is currently not supported (version 2.7).